# Using em for layout causes inconsistency across different browsers

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, font-size

I am trying to build a site using elastic layout. I have used Eric Meyer's CSS reset and also used `body {font-size:62.5%}` in my stylesheet.

Here is my HTML and CSS

```css
html {bacgroound:url() no-repeat top center fixed;}  

body {font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color:#000;
margin:auto;}

'id'other {background-color:color1;}  

'id'footer {background-color:color2;}
```

```html
<html>  
    <head>  
    </head>  
    <body>  
    <div id="container">  
        <div id="gallery">  
        </div>  
        <div id="other">  
        </div>  
    </div>  
    <div id="footer">  
    </div>  
    </body>  
</html>
```

As you can see, if I set a fixed width for the `body`, the `background` for `#other` and `#footer` remain fixed. So I tried to get around it by setting the `width` to `100%` and using `margin: 0 8em 0 8em` to center the gallery and the contents of `#other` and `#footer`.

The layout I am trying to achieve is basically a one-column layout containing a gallery of pictures. The whole gallery should be centered in the page. I have used `em` for defining `margin` and this causes different results in different browsers. If the gallery is centered in one browser, other browsers show a different result. I have tried Firefox, Chrome, and IE9.

Is there any way to produce identical layouts using `em` as the unit of measurement? Or should I try a fixed layout and use `px`instead of `em`?

Comment: It's going to be near impossible to tell *exactly* what's going on without a reference. Provide a link if you can.

Comment: Different browsers use different font settings and different systems use different font settings. Because of this, you cannot rely on `em` being the same across browsers. This is also why trying to use it as a basis for identical layouts is a bad idea; it's not designed for that. It's designed for font-sizes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep `em` or percentanges. [They](http://green-beast.com/blog/?p=199) **do** [work](http://jontangerine.com/log/2007/09/the-incredible-em-and-elastic-layouts-with-css).

However, using them for centering is probably part of your issue. Centering should be done with `auto`, for example:

```
div.page {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 925px;
}
```

Comment: You will also need to specify the width of the element for centering to work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Your inconsistency is a combination of things. Defining your `body {font-size: 62.5%}` is telling the browser to display the font at 62.5% of its base font-size setting (which is both user controlled and even variable per font). Then, using `em` later in the css cascade is again applying a scaling factor based upon the size of font as just defined (that scaling is harder to define: see http://webdesign.about.com/od/fonts/qt/em-origins.htm ). So a browser font set to `14px` will become `8.75px` (14 * .625) which (for sake of illustration) at `2em` theoretically might be `17.5px` (8.75 * 2). If the browser had a default 16px font, then the two numbers would be `10px` and theoretically `20px`.

So, to help with inconsistency in using `em` units, setting a `px` value and a universally recognizable font on the `body` tag (either standard web fonts or perhaps by `@font-face`) would help standardize `em` unit values lower in the css cascade.

Jason McCreary's answer is good if you have a "fixed width" container, but if you want to "fix the margin size" then your current idea of setting a `px` or `em` unit for your margins is just fine for centering.

Comment: +1 good point about the variable fonts. However, the OP did note using a reset style sheet. So what you describe *should* have minimal impact.

Comment: @Jason McCreary--But if the reset style sheet has body font set to a percentage (as the OP noted), then it is still user (browser) dependent on the initial font-size, which can have huge ramifications for later em sizing.